# How to search in DataGridView using access database?

Tags: c#, winforms, oledbdataadapter

I am working on a winform database application that update data using access database. In which I am trying to add textbox to search and filter data in datagridview (I connect my datagridview to Access Database using OleDb dataadapter.
My code for search text box is as follows:

```
private void txtSearchAdmin_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchAdmin.Text))
                dataGridView.DataSource = employeesBindingSource;
            else
            {
                var query = from o in this.adminData.Employees
                            where o.Customer_Name.Contains(txtSearchAdmin.Text) || o.Phone == txtSearchAdmin.Text || o.Address.Contains(txtSearchAdmin.Text)
                            select o;
                dataGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
          }
        }
```

Comment: so you have the code which searches in DataGridView/Access DB. what would be the question?

Comment: @Ash above mentioned code is for search in DGV. But its not working however it is searching but it hides first two rows and also I become unable to see data in DGV without restarting the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Abhi you currently using KeyPress event and this event fires before enter the text in the textbox, so you should use textbox TextChanged event.

```
private void txtSearchAdmin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchAdmin.Text))
                dataGridView.DataSource = employeesBindingSource;
            else
            {
                var query = from o in this.adminData.Employees
                            where o.Customer_Name.Contains(txtSearchAdmin.Text) || o.Phone == txtSearchAdmin.Text || o.Address.Contains(txtSearchAdmin.Text)
                            select o;
                dataGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
          }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Akash for help but again I am getting error for KeyChar. Because KeyChar doesn't work with TextChanged event. It is used for KeyPress. What is the substitute for this?

Comment: @Abhi why are you using -  if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)

Comment: Thanks Akash... I am very new to C# and that's why I did so. But now my code is working with text changed event successfully.